# How can I tell the validator of Vuelidate to accept "alphaNum" plus character dot(".")?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuelidate

I have an input field, I can tell **Vuelidate** that it only accepts `alphaNum` and `Required` like this:

```js
import { required, alphaNum } from "vuelidate/lib/validators";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      myInputValue: ""
    };
  },
  validations: {
    myInputValue: {
      required,
      alphaNum
    }
  }
};
```

Here comes my question, how can I make `myInputValue` to accept an additional character dot(.)?

Which will total accept these things

1. `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`
2. `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`
3. `0123456789`
4. `.`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What about `.foo`?

Comment: `.foo` will also accept

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a regular expression with a character set of alphanumeric characters plus `.`:

```
import { required, helpers } from 'vuelidate/lib/validators';
const alphaNumAndDotValidator = helpers.regex('alphaNumAndDot', /^[a-z\d.]*$/i);

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      myInputValue: ""
    };
  },
  validations: {
    myInputValue: {
      required,
      alphaNumAndDotValidator
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: @CertainPerformance beat me to it, but I'll still share my sandbox with the solution for others to play with: https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-overflow-q-60862345-ssioc